# Чтение *.CSV файла

Tags: java

Использую для чтение *.CSV файла

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sourceforge.javacsv</groupId>
  <artifactId>javacsv</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Имеется файл с переходами на другую строку. Например

```
CODE    DESCRIPTION 
AA  "Эта запись содержит:
- строку один;
- строку два;
- строку три."
```

Можно ли с помощью этой или какой-либо другой библиотеки прочитать такой файл?

Comment: JavaCSV должна уметь читать по умолчанию, поскольку в стандарте CSV оговорено, что если значение содержит перенос строки, то оно должно быть заключено в кавычки. Приведенный вами CSV соответствует стандарту. У вас что-то не получилось с этой библиотекой?

Comment: Из примера выше получается 4 записи... У последних трех CODE = NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV) каждая строка файла - это одна строка таблицы!
Постарайтесь заменить переносы на новую строку на "\n".

Comment: Из той же Википедии: "Значения, содержащие зарезервированные символы (двойная кавычка, запятая, точка с запятой, новая строка) обрамляются двойными кавычками (")"

Comment: Я полагаю, что символ \n (Если он является значение поля) долженбыть обрамлен в кавычки. Т.е нельзя использовать код :
`CODE    DESCRIPTION 
AA, \n`

Comment: @psih747, заменить переносы на новую строку? Это помогло бы если я составлял эти *.CSV файлы и производил их загрузку. Легче в таком случае немного изменить JavaCSV...

Comment: @Argos , советую попробовать еще [commons-csv](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/). Подберите свой формат, например [TDF](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#TDF) и, надеюсь, я у вас все получится.